# How to set a result if draggable is dropped in droppable in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to increase the value of a counter (`var counter = 0;`), if the draggable image on screen is dropped into the dropzone (also a image, not a `div`).

```
$( "#goldbag" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid", containment: "parent" });
$( "#jack2" ).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        draggedObj = ui.draggable.attr('id'); 
        $("#"+draggedObj).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });
        $( "img" ).draggable({ disabled: true });
    }
});
```

This code just fades out the droppable after its dropped on the image. Before/after it fades out I want to increment the counter by 1.

Note: Both `#goldbag` and `#jack2` are images (`<img>`) inside a single container `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend your `drop` callback function.
Here is an over simplified example, where you can drag and drop the same item multiple times while increasing a counter.

Most of this code was taken from the docs here: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

```js
$(function() {
  var $counter = $("#counter");
  var count = 0;
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
      count++;
      $counter.html(count);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<p>Counter: <span id="counter">0</span>
</p>
```